# What version of the TWAIN specification does the twain.dll that comes with Window 7 64bit implement?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, twain

I'm trying to determine what version of the TWAIN specification I can write my software to utilize and want to find out which version of the specification the twain.dll that comes with Win7 x64 implements.  The file info is as follows:

```
File Version: 1.7.0.0
Product Name: Twain Source Manager
Product Version: 1,7,0,0
Size: 92.5KB
Date Modified: 6/10/2009 5:41 PM
```

Am I even looking at the correct file to determine this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a 64bit version for windows 7 you'll need to grab the latest off of source forge which as of this writing is the 2.1 version,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-dsm/

and

http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/

The folks at Microsoft just haven't felt the need to update the version of the driver that they bundle with windows in some time.  So the one that's gets shipped is quite old, and only 32bit.